# 'ImportError: No module named scrapy' when executing exe in wine

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, pyinstaller, raspbian, wine

I am trying to execute an exe-file on my Raspberry Pi 3 using Exagear and Wine. When I execute the file, the following error occurs:

```
ImportError: No module named scrapy
[40] Failed to execute script mimi
fixme:module:load_library unsupported flag(s) used (flags: 0x00000800)
```

I installed Scrapy in Wine and built the exe with PyInstaller (in wine too).

I even created a file “hooks-data.py” with the content

```
hiddenimports=[‘pandas._libs.tslibs.timedelta’, ‘scrapy’]
```

The file is in the same directory as mimi.py. I used the command wine `pyinstaller -F --additional-hooks-dir=. mimi.py` to build the exe.

Still the exe-file cannot find the module scrapy when executed. Therefore, it seems to me that this is an exagear or a wine issue.

**Versions used:**

- Raspbian-Jesse 8
- Exagear-Desktop 2
- Wine 2.0
- Python 2.7.9
- Scrapy 1.5.1
- PyInsaller 3.4

**edit**

The same error occurs with and without Exagear. So error cannot be caused by it.

Comment: Can you start a python shell (simply executing `python` in a terminal)? If so, try entering `import scrapy`, does it output any errors?

Comment: The import statement works perfectly fine:
`wine python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scrapy
>>> 
`